# GNU Radio forecast() function for basic blocks

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am learning GNURadio for my academic studies. To implement the signal processing steps, I decided to write my blocks. But I haven't grasped the solid logic of the **basic** block.

Let's say I am writing a **basic** block that takes `N` input stream (where `N` is set by GNU Radio scheduler ofc.) and I know that my block will generate an output stream with the length of `M` (where `M` is less than or equal to `N`).

The pseudo-code of the  `general_work()` function in a Python-like fashion will be something like below. (The same code can be written in C++ as well) You can see the main reason for my problem which is indicated in the code section :

```py
def general_work(n_output, input_stream, output_stream):
    #n_output:      length of the input stream
    #input_stream:  input data array 
    #output_stream: output data array with the length of "n_output"

    # do processing
    y, len_y,n_consumed_input = my_foo(input_stream) # y is the processed signal with the length of "len_y"
                                                     # and "n_consumed_input" is the length of the input items consumed
    
    # Due to the nature of "my_foo()", len_y is always less than n_input"
    # which will be declared in the "forecast()" as "n_input = n_output", 
    # therefore "n_output>len_y" is always met.
 
    #embed the processed signal into the output stream 
    output_stream[:len_y] = y # -> MY QUESTION IS RELATED TO THIS LINE.
                              # -> IF IT IS LEGAL OR NOT?

    #consume the processed input stream from the buffer
    consume(n_consumed_input)

    # return the length of the produced output stream 
    return len_y
```

To perform the `output_stream[:len_y] = y`, it is trivial that the condition `len_y <= len(output_stream)` must be strictly met. Since the lengths of the input and output outputs are set by the GNURadio scheduler, we cannot know whether the following condition will be satisfied.
To solve this problem, we use the `forecast()` method which returns the necessary length for input stream and is called by the scheduler to ensure that the system will allocate an adequate amount of input signal length for performing the `general_work()` function.

As I commonly see from some of the examples of GNURadio, that `forecast()` function can be written as

```py
def forecast(n_output):
    n_input = n_output
    return n_input # I think that it is O.K. for my case since "len_y" is always less than "n_input"
```

And allocates memory for the output as much as the input uses. However, the `work()` function return `len_y` which is smaller than `n_input` that the `forecast()` method is allocated. Therefore, the system does not use `n_output-len_y` elements of the `output_stream` (in other words, `output_stream[-(n_output-len_y):]` will be not used).

My first question is that if it is the appropriate way to write a ***basic*** block.

Secondly, I wonder if the remaining part of the output stream (`output_stream[-(n_output-len_y):]`) is automatically freed by the scheduler of the GNURadio? If not, does it overflow the RAM?

## Example

Let us observe that `n_output = 5` is assigned by the scheduler and
due to the `forecast()` function that we wrote above, `n_input=5` as well.

In the `work()` function, firstly, `my_foo()` processes the signal and returns `y= [1,2,3], len_y = 3, n_consumed_input = 4` assign

Secondly, we assign `output_stream[:len_y] = y`. Therefore, the first 3 elements of `output_stream` are the actual produced signal, and, the last 2 elements have no significance.

After, we call the `consume(n_consumed_input)` to erase the input data that we used for producing output (`y`).

And lastly, we return `len_y` to tell the scheduler how many elements in `output_stream` we will use.

Thank you!

Comment: none of the descriptions of the parameters you give are *actually* correct: for the `general_work` function, you get input stream**s** (plural) and output stream**s** (plural), so, no, your code isn't correct. `forecast` gets a number of **output**, not input, items that your block is supposed to produces.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for your help! I've changed the content of the question. I made some mistakes while writing. I hope that the current version clarifies my problem further.

Comment: still not right. You can't just assigne a number to a vector's content in your forecast. and your `general_work` arguments are now even more incorrect!